# How to split 1D array in to arrays based on multiple keys - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, lodash

I have an 1D array like this, where a single object inside that array looks this

```
[
  {
    date: "01/01/2020",
    type1: 264,
    type2: 1937,
    type3: 30
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to modify the above array and convert it into a 2D array in the below format

```
[
  [
    {
      "date": "01/01/2020",
      "type": "type1",
      "value": 264
    },
    {
      "date": "01/01/2020",
      "type": "type2",
      "value": 1937
    }
    .....
  ],
  [
    {
      "date": "01/01/2020",
      "type": "type3",
      "value": 30
    }
    .....
  ]
]
```

Basically first array will consist of type1 and type2 values and the second array will consist of type3 value.

I am pretty new to javascript. I have tried this using plain javascript like below

```
const type1 = data.map((e: any) => ({
  date: e.date,
  type: "type1",
  value: e.type1
}));

const type2 = data.map((e: any) => ({
  date: e.date,
  type: "type2",
  value: e.type2
}));

const type3 = data.map((e: any) => ({
  date: e.date,
  type: "type3",
  value: e.type3
}));

const newData = [type1.concat(type2), type3];
```

Is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Your hard coded solution is clear and readable, so I would just stick to that. If you need a more dynamic solution in the future you can refactor. Prioritize clarity over cleverness.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, a way to convert the object(s) into the split up objects is to specify the property names (this is assuming there are no more unknown properties):

```js
const arr = [{date:'01/01/2020', type1:264,type2: 1937,type3:30}];

const res = _.flatMap(arr,o=> ['type1','type2','type3'].map(t=> ({date:o.date, type:t, value:o[t]})));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

After that though, I am not certain of the goal, If you want all objects of type 3 in a separate array, regardless of source object, a quick and dirty way could be:

```js
const arr = [{date:'01/01/2020', type1:264,type2: 1937,type3:30}];

const res = [[],[]];
  _.flatMap(arr,o=> ['type1','type2','type3'].map(t=> ({date:o.date, type:t, value:o[t]})))
  .forEach(o=> res[o.type==='type3' ? 1: 0].push(o));

console.log(res);
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I want type1 and type2 in the first array and type3 in the second array

Comment: Hi, they are in the bottom example in this post. (the first example is about creating the separate objects, the second about the grouping in arrays). Is that the format you are after?